# Selenium - Python/Django - Count records for a model

Tags: python, django, selenium

I newbie in Django/Python and moreover in functional testing
I use selenium

I try to test "add" in a model
so I try to calculate record number (`number = MyModel.objects.count()`) before and after adding to compare but my count return 0 even if there is 8 records in my database

it is not possible to count from a class test?

Comment: Tests run on a *different* database, if you do not specify the name yourself, it is `databasename_test`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: I have read that but I am a bit lost ; when I run "test" to create a models instance in a add form, it is created in my development database ; but if I delete this records and try to run again my test, it is impossible because record already exist... I try manage.py test --noinput but it does not work...

Comment: The test database is also destroyed each time it is used.

Comment: I really need help: I have made a copy of my sqlite db (test_db) and modifying DATABASE settings for selenium to use this test_db 'TEST': {
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test_db.sqlite3'),
        }, I would like to test **add of a record** in a model so I get number_before and number_after to compare with assertEqual(number_after,number_before+1) but it seams that my query did not query the database as result is always 0   I have made a classmethod that return the number of records in my models... thaks for your help